# How do I find if an int is in array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

I have an array with each index being another array. If I have an int, how can I write code to check whether the int is present within the first 2 indicies of each array element within the array in python.

eg:
3 in

```
array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

would produce False.

3 in

```
array = [[1,3,7], [4,5,6]]
```

would produce True.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *slice* your array to get a part of it, and then use `in` operator and `any()` function like this:

```
>>> array = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> [3 in elem[:2] for elem in array]
[False, False]
>>> any(3 in elem[:2] for elem in array)
False

>>> array = [[1,3,7], [4,5,6]]
>>> [3 in elem[:2] for elem in array]
[True, False]
>>> any(3 in elem[:2] for elem in array)
True
```

`any()` function returns `True` if at least one of the elements in the iterable is `True`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> print any(3 in b[:2] for b in a)
False

>>> a = [[1,3,7], [4,5,6]] 
>>> print any(3 in b[:2] for b in a)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The first way that comes to mind is

```
len([x for x in array if 3 in x[:2]]) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.array`

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]) 
a2 = np.array([[1,3,7], [4,5,6]])
```

You can do:

```
>>> a1[:, :2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
>>> 3 in a1[:, :2]
False
>>> 3 in a2[:, :2]
True
```